# How to get the holidays date in my case?

Tags: javascript, date, object

I am trying to get the holidays of given range of dates.

For example:

```
var holiday = ['2014-01-01','2014-07-04','2014-12-24', '2014-12-25'...other holidays elements ];

var startDate = '2014-08-01'
var endDate = '2014-12-30';

var holidays=getHolidays(startDate, endDate);
//console.log(holidays) -> output 2014-12-24 and 2014-12-25.

getHolidays = function(startDate, endDate) {
    var holidays=[];
    //not sure how to get holidays here....
    return holidays
}
```

I was hoping to write a function to get 2014-12-24 and 2014-12-25. My brain is fried now and I don't know what's the best approach on this. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is `getHolidays()` meant to return? Your question is fairly vague (actually, what's your question?).

Comment: the function can return a list of holidays. I don't know where to begin so I didn't put anything inside it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to use filter function of array. The first parameter is the array you need to filter, and in your case, it's ['2014-01-01', '2014-07-04', '2014-12-24', '2014-12-25'].

```
var getHolidays = function(holiday,startDate, endDate) {
    return holiday.filter(function(element){
        var start = new Date(startDate);
        var end = new Date(endDate);
        var temp = new Date(element);
        return temp >= start && temp <= end;
    });
}

var holiday = ['2014-01-01', '2014-07-04', '2014-12-24', '2014-12-25'];
var startDate = '2014-08-01'
var endDate = '2014-12-30';
var holidays = getHolidays(holiday,startDate, endDate); //["2014-12-24", "2014-12-25"]
```

It works exactly as what you expect as shown in 
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bruceyang/67j7nsh9/)

Answer (score 1):

You could try turning them into date objects, and then comparing them that way.  Something like:

```
var holidays = ['2014-01-01','2014-07-04','2014-12-24', '2014-12-25'];

var startDate = '2014-08-01';
var endDate = '2014-12-30';

var getHolidays = function(startDate, endDate) {
    var startTime = new Date(startDate).getTime();
    var endTime = new Date(endDate).getTime();
    var output = [];

    holidays.forEach(function(holiday) {
        var holidayTime = new Date(holiday).getTime();

        if (holidayTime >= startTime && holidayTime <= endTime) {
            output.push(holiday);
        }
    });

    return output;
}


var holidays = getHolidays(startDate, endDate);

console.log(holidays);
```

Comment: thanks! Could you please explain what the holiday variable is? +1

Comment: I made your original list of holiday dates into an array called `holidays`.  The `holiday` variable on the line with the `forEach` is the parameter automatically passed in.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach for more details.

Comment: Please don't use the Date constructor to parse strings, it is unreliable at best. Use a simple parse function.

Answer (score 0):

As plain strings, the *getHolidays* function can be:

```
// Get holidays between two dates
function getHolidays(startDate, endDate) {
  var output = [];
  var i = 0;
  var holiday;

  while ((holiday = holidays[i++]) && holiday < endDate) {
    if (startDate <= holiday) {
      output.push(holiday)
    }
  }
  return output;
}
```

If you are using ISO 8601 date strings, there's no need to convert them to Date objects. One of the reasons for the ISO format is that in most systems, you can compare strings directly rather than Date objects or some number value.

You can also parse the strings to Date objects, then use those to do the calculations but it takes more code for no real benefit:

```
// Parse date string in y-m-d format
function parseYMD(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  var d = new Date();
  d.setHours(0,0,0,0);
  d.setFullYear(b[0], --b[1], b[2]);
  return d.getFullYear() == b[0] && d.getDate() == b[2]? d : NaN;
}

// Holiday array
var holidays = ['2014-01-01','2014-07-04','2014-12-24', '2014-12-25'];

// Get holidays between two dates
function getHolidays(startDate, endDate) {
  startDate = parseYMD(startDate);
  endDate   = parseYMD(endDate);
  var output = [];
  var i = 0;
  var holiday;

  for (var i=0, iLen=holidays.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    holiday = parseYMD(holidays[i]);

    if (holiday <= endDate) {
      if (holiday >= startDate) {
        output.push(holidays[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  return output; 
}

console.log(getHolidays('2014-08-01', '2014-12-30')); // ["2014-12-24", "2014-12-25"]
```